# ComboBox in WPF/MVVM with null and empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, inotifypropertychanged

I have a problem with my ComboBox in WPF/MVVM project. After changing ViewModel (I use everything correctly: `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `ObservableCollection`, etc.) the ComboBox is not always changes its value. I've debugged it and the getter from ViewModel returned the correct value (`string.Empty`), but the ComboBox displayed a value from the list. A bit of code below:

```
// It doesn't work.
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

// It works.
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

TextBlock is updated correctly if SelectedItem is `string.Empty` or `null`, but ComboBox is not updated correctly (old value stays) if SelectedItem is `string.Empty`. It's cleared only if SelectedItem is `null` value.
Why is this occurring?

// **EDIT**:

Maybe I explained it wrong. I have two grids: on the left I have tree with files and on the right I have properties of selected file. When I first select file `A`, which doesn't have setted property, the ComboBox is empty. If I choose file `B`, which have this property setted, it appers in the ComboBox. Next if I select file `C` with empty property, the old value stays in ComboBox (from before selected file - `B`). If this property from `C` is `null`, not `string.Empty`, ComboBox is cleared.

Comment: I've forgotten to add, that I change ViewModel (for file actualy) and if next file (ViewModel) has empty SelectedItem, combobox doesn't change its value.

Comment: Since you're dealing with strings have you tried using `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Yes, this is solution. But I don't understand why it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Use CollectionViewSource instead of ObservableCollection for ComboBox.